# Tempered Distribution Calculation

Tags: fourier-analysis

I hope you don't mind that rather than typing this question up I took a screenshot and uploaded it:

http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~schlitt/stackexchangeproblems/tempered-distributions-calc.png

The step that I can't follow is the one clearly identified in red.

It's an integration change of variable I think that is really confusing me.

Update:

I tried doing integration by parts using $u = F(t)$ and $dv = \phi'(t)dt$.

I get

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int F(t)\;d\phi(t) &=& \int F(t)\phi'(t)\;dt\\
&=& F(t)\phi(t) - \int \phi(t)F'(t)\;dt\\
&=& F(t)\phi(t) - \int \phi(t)\;dF(t)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: No, it is an integration by part that uses the properties of the support of the functions.

Comment: I was going to post an answer that said it's just integration by parts, but Jon has already posted that as a comment.

Comment: I tried that, see my edit above.  What happened to the $F(t)\phi(t)$ term?

Comment: That term vanished because of the definition of "tempered distribution", i.e. its limit as $t\to\pm\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: Facepalm...

I completely forgot I was dealing with a improper definite integral.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there some Stieltjes-integral involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I post it as an answer. It is just an integration by parts that uses the fact that "tempered distributions" imply 0 in the limit $t\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I realize that the answer was exactly what you said the first time.  I completely forgot I was dealing with a improper definite integral.